# Reference for proving $[L:K]=e[\mathcal O_L/\mathfrak{m}_L:\mathcal O_K/ \mathfrak{m}_K]$ for e - ramification index

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

I am given complete discrete valuation fields $K$ and $L$, finite extension $K\subset L$, corresponding d.v.r. $\mathcal O_K$ and $\mathcal O_L$ with maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}_K$ and $\mathfrak{m}_L$. By $e$ I denote ramification index for $K\subset L$, that is $v_L(\pi_K)=e$ for $(\pi_K)=\mathfrak{m}_K.$ It is also noted that $\mathcal O_K/ \mathfrak{m}_K$ is finite.

I would like to learn how to prove $[L:K]=e[\mathcal O_L/\mathfrak{m}_L:\mathcal O_K/ \mathfrak{m}_K]$, however I did not quite understand proof from lecture. Does anyone know where can I find proof for that?

Thanks.

Comment: Theorem 3.34 of [Milne's notes on algebraic number theory](https://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf) gives a nice proof (in a bit more generality—in your setting you just have one prime lying above the given prime of the base field, which slightly simplifies parts of the proof).

Comment: The answers to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960943 discuss "$n=ef$" for finite extensions of $\mathbf Q_p$ in two different ways.

Comment: Thank you both for wonderful sources!